# Linear probing 16 hashmap elements in parallel using SIMD instrinsics

Tags: c, hash-map, simd

For my hashmap implementation, I'm caching hashes for each map element in an array of length `NBUCKETS`, where each element corresponds to an element in the hashmap. Assuming a hash consists of 64-bits, the first 57 bits decide the position(bucket) in the hashmap and the last 7 bits (i.e `H2(hash)`) are used as control bytes for probing the table. More concretely, while finding an element in the map using linear probing, `H2(hash)` is compared for 16 elements at a time using SIMD intrinsics before comparing actual keys. Hence, each call to `probe_group()` probes 16 elements of the map at the same time.

Components of code where I think optimization is needed but don't know how to do so (these have TODO tags in code):

1. Populating the `group` array with 16 elements from `hash_arr` is expensive. I want to avoid the usage of temporary `group` array and load the last 7 bits of 16 consecutive hash values from `hash_arr` directly into a `__m128i` (i.e `ctrl`).  Is there a way to directly load the last 7 bits of 16 hash values from `hash_arr` into `__m128i` instead of using the temporary byte array `group`?
2. Checking which indices have bit 1 is expensive because my current implementations applies `(match >> i) & 1U` for each index `i`, where `i` ranges from 0 to 15 inclusive. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Any suggestions on improving these components as well as others parts of the code will be deeply appreciated.

````c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NBUCKETS 100
#define GROUP_SIZE 16

typedef char h2_t;

// return the lowest byte 
static inline h2_t H2(size_t hash)
{
    return hash & 0x7f;
}

// If ith element in `group` is 'hash', then ith bit in `match` will be 1,
// otherwise it will be 0
static inline uint16_t probe_group(h2_t hash, h2_t *group)
{

    __m128i ctrl  = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) group);
    __m128i match = _mm_set1_epi8(hash);
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(match, ctrl));
}

int main()
{
    // Dummy array of hashes. Each element corresponds to an element at that index in the hashmap.
    size_t hash_arr[NBUCKETS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NBUCKETS; i++)
        hash_arr[i] = i;

    // TODO Optimize this: Avoid using this array. Instead load the last 7 bits of 16 hash values directly into a `__m128i`.
    const int start_pos = 90;
    h2_t group[GROUP_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUP_SIZE; i++)
        group[i] = H2(hash_arr[(start_pos + i) % NBUCKETS]);

    // Element to be searched for in `group`.  ASCII for 'c' is 99
    h2_t find_ele = 'c';

    uint16_t match = probe_group(find_ele, group);

    // TODO Optimize this: Find a better way to check which indices have bit 1
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUP_SIZE; i++) {
        if ((match >> i) & 1U)
            printf("Element at index %d in group is equal to %c\n", i, find_ele);
    }
}
```
````